# Recruit Distribution job search pages

Tags: blocks, distributions

I am using recruit distribution, I have configured everything but one thing that is giving me headache is how can I change the blocks in the jobs search page, I could not find any way nor any template file where I could make any changes for this page.
Please find the link below to get an idea.

http://drupaljobs.epiqo.com/search/job?search=&field_job_region_parents_all=

On the left sidebar I dont have any option to add any new facet block, I am confused is it a panel page or through template.if its a template then which template file is installing this sidebar, Same is the case with the recruit resume search page.

Please find the screenshot attached
[image]